# Add column from one table to another

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have the following tables:

Table A:

```
 ___________________
|    ID    | NUMBER |
|__________|________|
| 10000378 |    1   |  
|          |        |
```

Table B:

```
 _________________________________________________
|     ...    |    ID    |  Column 1  |  Column 2  |
|____________|__________|____________|____________|
|     ...    | 10000378 |      7     |      2     |
|            |          |            |            |
```

`Table A` and `Table B` share the same `ID` value.

Not that it matters too much, the `ID` in `Table A` is it's key, and can be found in `Table B`.

`Table A`'s `NUMBER` column tells me which `Table B` column to read.

For example:

```
IF
    [Table A].[NUMBER] = 1
THEN
    put the value of [Table B].[Column 1] into [Table B].[My Column]

  ... and so on
```

As a visual example (**my desired result**):

```
 _______________________________________________________________
|     ...    |    ID    |  Column 1  |  Column 2  |  My Column  |
|____________|__________|____________|____________|_____________|
|     ...    | 10000378 |      7     |      2     |      7      |
|            |          |            |            |             |
```

With `My Column` being the result I am after (which comes from `Column 1` - as specified by `Table A`'s `NUMBER` value for the ID of `10000378`).

#### What I have tried so far

I have set up a `1-to-1` relationship between `Table A` and `Table B` (on the `ID` column`).

I then went into the `Power Query Editor` tried adding a `Conditional Column`:

[image: screenshot]

But that doesn't allow me to reference `Table A` in any way.

So I decided to try the `Append Queries as New` option:

[image: screenshot]

Selecting the `Two tables` radio button, setting `Primary Table` to `Table B` and `Table to append to the primary table` to `Table B`.

With the idea of creating the following structure from which I can get my desired result (but adding the `NUMBER` column, which I don't really want but can live with):

```
 _____________________________________________________________________________
|     ...    |    ID    |  Column 1  |  Column 2  |   NUMBER    |  My Column  |
|____________|__________|____________|____________|_____________|_____________|
|     ...    | 10000378 |      7     |      2     |      1      |      7      |
|            |          |            |            |             |             |
```

Doing the append copied all of the contents of `Table B` and inserted the `NUMBER` column which is fine, but all the values in that `NUMBER` column are now `null`.

I don't understand why this is the case.

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: You need to [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-shape-and-combine-data#combine-queries) these tables, not to append them.

Comment: Understood. Mind posting this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending queries is used when you have additional rows of data that you’d like to add to an existing query (i.e. union/union all in SQL). Joining tables in Power BI is called "merging":

[image]

You can find more details in [Combine queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-shape-and-combine-data#combine-queries) section of [Tutorial: Shape and combine data in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-shape-and-combine-data) article.

Note that if you have a proper relationship defined between your tables in the model (also described in the article above).

Answer (score 1):

To do this, first *merge* `Table B` with `Table A` and expand the columns you'd like to add to the table (`Column 1` and `Column 2`).

Once you have that, then write your custom column, `My Column`:

```
if [NUMBER] = 1 then [Column 1]
else if [NUMBER] = 2 then [Column 2]
else <whatever you want to return if not 1 or 2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accepted a different answer because it was first but gave you an upvote for the explanation anyway.